# Python: What is the best way of creating a png of a map with a route for a written report?

Tags: python, google-maps, dictionary, png, openstreetmap

I'm looking for a way to make png files of maps within a python script that show travels as lines (I have the coordinates already as lat, long and elevation). As far as I know, it is not legal to use google maps "offline" or printed, so I'm targeting for OpenStreet Maps.

Can you recommend me a way to do this? Any module that can help me? or even an example?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot recomend [tilemill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) highly enough for this sort of task.  It will let you choose a base map from a large selection or import and style your own from OSM data.  It also has very good support for data layers like your route.  Most importantly it has fantastic documentation and [tutorials](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/introduction/).

If you want to stay entirely in python then I recomend using the [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) library.

You will need a datafile, like the shapefile [here](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/physical/ne_110m_coastline.zip):

`ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp`

An xml style file:

```
<Map background-color="black" srs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs">
  <Style name="My Style">
    <Rule>
      <PolygonSymbolizer fill="#f2eff9" />
      <LineSymbolizer stroke="rgb(50%,50%,50%)" stroke-width="5.0" />
    </Rule>
  </Style>
  <Layer name="world" srs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs">
    <StyleName>My Style</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
      <Parameter name="type">shape</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="file">ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
</Map>
```

and a python script:

```
import mapnik
stylesheet = 'world_style.xml'
image = 'world_style.png'
m = mapnik.Map(2000, 1500)
mapnik.load_map(m, stylesheet)
m.zoom_all() 
mapnik.render_to_file(m, image)
print "rendered image to '%s'" % image
```